# Assigning values for the first time inside a func with a bunch of if's, need to get rid of if's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I'm building a little script in JavaScript to work with firebase ... it works so far as intended but a coworker told me that there was a way to fix those `if` and get rid of them for good practices, and because if I add another `if` in the future, our eslint rules will jump and it will not allow me to work even further... I've been thinking about this for two days now and still can't figure how to get rid of them. Heres the code:

```
  const dataFirebase = {};
  inputs.map(item => {
    dataFirebase[item.data] = item.ref.current.value;
  });
  const dataSelect = () => {
    if (selectA) dataFirebase.A = ARef.current.textContent;
    if (selectB) dataFirebase.B = BRef.current.textContent;
    if (selectC) dataFirebase.C = CRef.current.textContent;
    if (selectD) dataFirebase.D = DRef.current.textContent;
    if (selectE) dataFirebase.E = EVendido;
  };
  dataSelect();
```

What I basically do there is assign the data for the first time to that function `dataSelect` but if the condition is met ... and then assign the value.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at Switch statements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Hello! I already checked the Switch statements but they wont work for me as it will happen the same thing... I will end up with 5 switches ... 

Comment: I think we need more context in that case. Where does selectA, selectB etc. come from?